# GoLang Gin - шаблонизация HTML страниц

Tags: веб-программирование, golang, сеть, веб-сервер

Вопрос по использованию шаблонизатора GIN + React фронтенд.

Допустим, пользователь начал регистрироваться на сайте. Ввёл свою почту, затем ввёл код с почты и сейчас ему остаётся придумать пароль.
Но пользователь решает обновить страницу, и надо сделать так, чтобы пользователь увидел поле ввода пароля, а не начальный этап процедуры регистрации — ввод почты.

Я вижу два способа решения этой задачи:

1. Перед тем как отправить страницу регистрации, по куках проверяем что пользователь уже сделал и изменяем шаблон:

   ```
    func (h *Handler) Join(ctx *gin.Context) {
    if isCodeSent(ctx) {

        ctx.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{ // Отображаем поле ввода кода с почты
            "body":  template.HTML(_templateConfirmationCode)
        })

        return
    }

    if isMailConfirmed(ctx) {
        ctx.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{ /// Отображаем поле ввода пароля
            "body": template.HTML(_templatePassword),
        })
        return
    }

    ctx.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{"body": template.HTML(`<body>`)})
   ```

   }

2. Переложить всю ответственность за отображение страниц на фронтенд. Соответственно после обновления страницы будем запускать какой-нибудь лоадер и спрашивать сервер по роуту /get-status про текущее состояние и уже отображать нужный этап.

> Какой подход считается правильным и что мне выбрать?

Comment: Оба подхода правильные :) вопрос в том что вы хотите :)

Comment: Второй подход, как по мне, более медленный, так как отправляет дополнительный запрос чтобы узнать статус. Хотя такой статус можно вшить прямо в HTML как json, а на фронтенд распарсить.

Мне в общем интересно, что обычно лучше использовать. Вот к примеру именно для моего случая с регистрацией.

Comment: Оба подхода верны и позволяют добиться разного поведения, ваш текущий вопрос можно верно решить обоими методами. Поэтому решение нужно принимать исходя из того будут ли где либо еще эти данные использоваться в таком же отдельном виде, и нужна ли вам оптимизация при запросе этих параметров или нужна универсальность...